# Is there a way in Realm to implement order_by for nested objects

Tags: ios, swift, realm, sql-order-by

I am trying to retrieve nested objects sorted in a specific order when I retrieve the parent object using realm.objects(). And equally importantly, maintain the sort order if any nested object is modified.

I have searched related issues but they are either dated or not quite the issue I am describing

Here's an example: I have 'user's in Realm, each of which have 'task's (with extraneous fields omitted for clarity)

```
class task: Object {
    @objc dynamic var priority = 10
}

class user: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    let tasks = List<task>()
}
```

I create a few users and then append tasks for any given user (a table in my UI with section for each User and Tasks for that User as rows in that user's section, SORTED by priority).

Default priority starts at 10, and can be changed in the range from 1-10 at any time.

When I retrieve users:

```
// (1)
users = realm.objects(user.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "name")
```

I want to retrieve their tasks sorted by priority.

Note that the priority is modified after the initial retrieval of users (meaning Results's task object's priority is changed under a realm.write()). To clarify, somewhere in my code, for a given user's task, I do the following:

```
realm.write() {
    task1.priority = newPriority
?
```

Which means that the user's task list should always be sorted by priority and not require repeating (1) above. I can't sort the user.tasks property because it is a "let" variable.

Note that both user and task objects have a sort order.

I could do index(remove/add) on tasks after I update 'priority' above but have not tried this yet. However, rather than do this manually (and assuming it works, and assuming there isn't a delete/add of 'task' happening alongside the reshuflle, ...), isn't that the whole idea behind ORMs, to make such things straightforward?

Anyway to do this? With Extensions on Realm? ??? Open to suggestions on alternative approaches vs nested objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question and an answer that really shows off Realms live updating capability.

Restating the question

> A user has tasks and we want to work with those tasks as an ordered
>   list, and if there's a change to the order, keep them ordered by the new order

Using the two classes presented in the question, we have a button that calls a function to query realm for a user and store that user in a class var

```
var myUser: UserClass!

func loadUser() {
    if let realm = gGetRealm() { //my code to connect to Realm
        let userResults = realm.objects(UserClass.self)
        if userResults.count > 0 {
            let user = userResults[0]
            self.myUser = user
        }
    }
}
```

then a button that calls a function to simply print out that users tasks, ordered by priority

```
func printOrderedTasks() {
    let sortedTasks = self.myUser.tasks.sorted(byKeyPath: "priority")
    for task in sortedTasks {
        print(task)
    }
}
```

So for this example, I created 4 tasks, and added them to a users tasks list and wrote the user to realm, the priority initial order is: 10, 0, 1, 4

Then loadUser loads in and store the first user available and assigned it to the class var.

The printOrderedTasks outputs the tasks, in ascending order. So after loading the user, clicking printOrderedTasks the output is

```
0
1
4
10
```

then, using Realm Studio, change the 1 to a 6 and click the printOrderedTasks again and the output is

```
0
4
6
10
```

without having to reload anything.

Realm objects are live updating so as long as you have a reference to them in your code, any changes are reflected live.

You could expand upon this by adding an observer to that object and Realm will notify the app of the event, to which you could reload a tableView or let the user know of the change.

**Edit:**

To take this a step further, the users tasks are also live updating objects and if you set a sort on them, those results maintain their sort.

For example, let's re-write the above code to keep track of a users tasks that maintain a live sort. I've re-written the above code and eliminated the user class var and added a tasks class var. Note that we never need to re-sort the tasks, the sort order is set initially and they will stay sorted from that point forward.

```
var myUserTasks: Results<TaskClass>!

func loadUserAndGetTasks() {
    if let realm = gGetRealm() {
        let userResults = realm.objects(UserClass.self)
        if userResults.count > 0 {
            let user = userResults[0]
            self.myUserTasks = user.tasks.sorted(byKeyPath: "priority")
        }
    }
}

func printTasks() {
    for t in self.myUserTasks {
        print(t)
    }
}
```

The initial order was 10, 0, 1, 4 as above. If we then change the 1 to a six using Realm Studio, and then run the printTasks function, you'll see the ordering was automagically done because the Results are live updating.

```
0
4
6
10
```

The cool thing here is that you don't need to keep resorting the tasks - they maintain their sort order.

Comment: I like this answer. I actually tried this when I figured I could not sort in place, but just did not care for that extra variable floating around (not that the tasks are displayed in UITableView). I just felt that that is not efficient if I have to maintain something outside of Realm that realm should provide (sorry, I've been spoilt by SQLAlchemy).  But Chris Shaw I believe has nailed it. More there...

Answer (score 1):

@Jay's answer is great as always, but I'd take his suggestion and make it intrinsic to the user object. This is my 'usual' way of handling requirements such as this.

As you say, the `user` object `tasks` property is a `let`, but this is how a Realm object is defined. That's not to say you can't add your own computed properties to control access to the object.

If you only want to see the tasks as an ordered list, then add a property that gives you that, e.g.

```
extension user
{
  var orderedTasks: Results<task>
  {
    return tasks.sorted(byKeyPath: "priority")
  }
}
```

Then always use that property to access the tasks. Using an extension there is my own style - I just keep the data declarations in the class declaration, and then add an extension with any computed properties or functions - but you can just add the declaration straight into the class definition.

Comment: This is very good Chris. Elegance in simplicity. However, given the variable is called frequently, I am often sorting an already sorted list. For example, I am updating a table, and the view asks for row data one at a time, which would be an index into 'orderedTasks', but won't it get sorted every time I reference it? I can set a flag... hmmmm. Having said this, there only are a few (typically less than 10, more like 5-6) tasks so might not cost me much. Plus I am not sorting all users tasks, it's per user (based on an interaction). I am going to go with this.

Comment: "I am often sorting an already sorted list.". Not exactly, as this property does not give you a sorted list. Rather, it gives you a query by which to access a sorted list. It's a subtle distinction, but important to how Realm works. For example, in your table view you could take a copy of the property at start-up (`tasks = user.orderedTasks`), but this would make no difference to accessing the property directly each time in terms of performing a sort.

Comment: @retd111 I may be missing something but this is essentially the exact same solution as in my answer, but by adding an extension. You still have to have a maintain a reference to the user object in order to get ordered tasks which means it's still 'floating around'. That's the nature of Realm - if you want live updating objects, you need to keep a reference to that object. Otherwise, it will have to be re-loaded each time to get fresh data. That extends out to events as well - you need to keep a reference to the Results that are being observed so you will receive an event when a change happens.

Comment: Jay, you are quite right about "exact same solution".